# How to run two anonymous struct in the same file?

Tags: html, go

In this code, I have two messages.

1- First one is **signupsuccess** that your account is created. Now login to an account and

2- The second is **loginfailure** that is if an email or password does not match then give an error message.

I have called both messages in the `login.html` file but when I run this code, it prefers to run only the first message that is

```
 <div class="loginfailure">
        <h1>{{.Loginfailure}}</h1>
    </div>
```

It does not allow the second one and if the second message is called, it gives the blank page.

**handler.go**

**Signup success**

```
success := struct{ Signupsuccess string }{Signupsuccess: "Your account is successfully created"}
loginTmpl.Execute(w, success)
```

**Login failure**

```
failure := struct{ Loginfailure string }{Loginfailure: "Enter the correct email or password"}
loginTmpl.Execute(w, failure)
```

**login.html**

```
{{define "body"}}
    <div class="loginfailure">
        <h1>{{.Loginfailure}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="signupsuccess">
        <h1>{{.Signupsuccess}}</h1>
    </div>
    <h1>Log In</h1>  
    <p>Login to access your account</p>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="/signup" class="link">Signup</a>
        </div>
    </form>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check the error returned by `Execute`.

Inside the template you can't reference a field that does not exist in the struct that you passed to the template, i.e. when you pass `failure` the `{{.Signupsuccess}}` action breaks the template, when you pass `success` the `{{.Loginfailure}}` breaks the template.

---

You can use maps, referencing map keys that are not present in the map *is allowed*

```golang
success := map[string]string{"Signupsuccess": "Your account is successfully created"}
if err := oginTmpl.Execute(w, success); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

```golang
failure := map[string]string{"Loginfailure": "Enter the correct email or password"}
if err := loginTmpl.Execute(w, failure); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Or use a single struct that has both fields

```golang
type TemplateData struct {
    Signupsuccess string
    Loginfailure string
}
```

```golang
success := TemplateData{Signupsuccess: "Your account is successfully created"}
if err := oginTmpl.Execute(w, success); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

```golang
failure := TemplateData{Loginfailure: "Enter the correct email or password"}
if err := loginTmpl.Execute(w, failure); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```